# Layout Cycle Detected error Windows 8.1 Gridview

Tags: gridview, prism, windows-8.1, virtualization

I am currently using Prism WinRT in my project.

Based on web search this is what i have tried:

1. Removed progress bar from data template,( this should have been fixed in Win 8.1 though)
2. Added fixed width and height to image

I found that Progress Bar has that bug and i removed it from my data-template, but i still see the bug.

On initial load everything seems fine, but when i change the data collection in view model based on filter chosen by users, and start to scroll i hit this issue intermittently. Is there any event that i should be waiting for before letting users scroll.

If i use a stackpanel as the ItemsPanel then i don't see this bug, but then i loose the virtualization capability and it takes forever to display large data sets.

I have presented the code as its there in the app, i can simplify it if anyone wants.

```
    <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
        <GridView Style="{StaticResource mainGridViewStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}" Name="itemsGridView" common:GridViewItemClickedCommand.Command="{Binding ItemClickedCommand}"  />
    </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>

    <CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="itemsViewSource"
            Source="{Binding PageData}"
            IsSourceGrouped="True"
            ItemsPath="Contents"
            />

    <Style x:Key="mainGridViewStyle" TargetType="GridView">
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="ItemsGridView"/>
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Items"/>
        <Setter Property="TabIndex" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="120,0,0,50"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Multiple"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSwipeEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="IsItemClickEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsGridViewEnabled}"/>
        <Setter Property="CanReorderItems" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CanDragItems" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="ShowsScrollingPlaceholders" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplateSelector" Value="{StaticResource    gridViewTemplateSelector}"/>

        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="GroupStyleSelector" Value="{StaticResource GridViewGroupStyleSelector}"/>    
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid GroupPadding="0,0,80,0" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="1"/>
    </Style>

     <views:ViewTemplateSelector x:Key="gridViewTemplateSelector" 
                                iconViewTemplate="{StaticResource iconViewTemplate}"
                                thumbnailViewTemplate="{StaticResource thumbnailViewTemplate}"/>



     <DataTemplate x:Key="iconViewTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="itemMainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Height="75" Background="White" Margin="0,0,5,5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="90*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ProgressRing x:Name="contentUpdatingProgressBar" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0.5" IsActive="{Binding IsContentUpdating}" Foreground="{StaticResource AppHeaderForeGroundColor}" Visibility="{Binding IsContentUpdating, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConvertor}}">

            </ProgressRing>
            <Image x:Name="iconImage" Source="{Binding FileIconLink}" Stretch="UniformToFill"  Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="5" Width='75" Height ="75">
                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ImageFailed">
                        <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Source" Value="{Binding FileIconLink}"/>
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>

                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Image>

            <TextBlock x:Name="contentName" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="2" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="Black" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="contentSize" Text="{Binding FormattedSize,TargetNullValue=''}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="Black" Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding FormattedSize, Converter={StaticResource SizeVisibilityConvertor}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

            </TextBlock>

            <StackPanel x:Name="transferStatusPanel" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContentStatus}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="8" Margin="2,0,2,0" Foreground="Black" Visibility="{Binding ContentStatus, Converter={StaticResource SizeVisibilityConvertor}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TransferProgress}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="8" Margin="2,0,1,0" Foreground="Black" Visibility="{Binding IsTransferActive, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConvertor}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text=" %" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="8" Margin="0,0,2,0" Foreground="Black" Visibility="{Binding IsTransferActive, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConvertor}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                </TextBlock>
                <!--ProgressBar Visibility="{Binding IsTransferActive, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConvertor}}" Margin="2" Value="{Binding TransferProgress, FallbackValue=0}" Foreground="Blue" Background="Gray" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/-->

            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>

    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="thumbnailViewTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="itemMainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="0,0,5,5">
            <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <Image x:Name="iconImage" Source="{Binding ThumbnailLink}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width='150" Height ="150">
                    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ImageFailed">
                            <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Source" Value="{Binding FileIconLink}"/>
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>


                    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </Image>
            </Border>

            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">

                <ProgressRing x:Name="contentUpdatingProgressBar" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" IsActive="{Binding IsContentUpdating}" Foreground="{StaticResource AppHeaderForeGroundColor}" Visibility="{Binding IsContentUpdating, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConvertor}}">

                </ProgressRing>
                <TextBlock x:Name="contentName" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" Margin="15,0,15,0">


                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock x:Name="contentSize" Text="{Binding FormattedSize,TargetNullValue=''}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">


                </TextBlock>
                <StackPanel x:Name="transferStatusPanel" Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContentStatus}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="8" Margin="2,0,2,0" Foreground="Black" Visibility="{Binding ContentStatus, Converter={StaticResource SizeVisibilityConvertor}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TransferProgress}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="8" Margin="2,0,1,0" Foreground="Black" Visibility="{Binding IsTransferActive, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConvertor}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text=" %" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="8" Margin="0,0,2,0" Foreground="Black" Visibility="{Binding IsTransferActive, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConvertor}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <!--ProgressBar Visibility="{Binding IsTransferActive, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConvertor}}" Margin="2" Value="{Binding TransferProgress, FallbackValue=0}" Foreground="Blue" Background="Gray" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/-->

                </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate> 

    <GroupStyle x:Key="gridViewGroupStyle" HidesIfEmpty="True">
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="headerGrid">
                    <Button x:Name="headerButton" Content='{Binding Name}' Background="Transparent" Foreground="AliceBlue" Margin="0" Padding="0,5,5,5" BorderThickness="0" Command="{Binding DataContext.HeaderCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                                           IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" CommandParameter="{Binding HeaderIdentifier}" FontFamily="Global User Interface" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>





    public class ViewTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate iconViewTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate thumbnailViewTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (Utilities.GridviewItemStyle == GridviewItemStyle.IconStyle)
                return iconViewTemplate;
            else
                return thumbnailViewTemplate;

        }
    }


    public class GridViewGroupStyleSelector : GroupStyleSelector
    {
        protected override GroupStyle SelectGroupStyleCore(object group, uint level)
        {
            return (GroupStyle)App.Current.Resources["gridViewGroupStyle"];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So i was unable to figure this out, but navigating to the same page again with different parameter ( I tweaked the frame journal to not add these entries to navigation history) solved the problem. Somewhere recycling of ui-elements is causing a cycle.